# Can we use xwork validation framework to validate pojo in service layer

Tags: java, xwork

Can we use xwork validation framework to validate pojo in service layer? It seems we have to extend ActionSupport class which is part of presentation layer to use xwork validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionSupport class is pojo. It doesn't have any dependency of servlet, hence we can use xwork to validate data objects in service layer.